# Is 'maintenance work' a tautology?

Tags: word-choice

Which of these is preferable? Is it considered tautology (or pleonasm) or flabby writing?

We are performing scheduled maintenance work on Friday.

We are performing scheduled maintenance on Friday.

Comment: Both seem OK to me, neither is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

No!  You have other types of work, such as construction.

Comment: Also, while *it was tiring maintenance work* makes sense, *it was tiring maintenance* does not. (There are several contexts in which you can't just replace one with the other.)